# mySQL Variables in SELECT

Tags: sql, mysql, t-sql

Is it possible to have a query such as the following:

```
SELECT
@threadIDvar = `threads`.`id` AS `threadID`,
(SELECT `posts`.`timeDate` FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`threadID` = @threadIDvar) AS `postDate`
FROM `threads`
INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`threadID` = `threads`.`id`
WHERE `threads`.`boardID` = 1
```

I have tried it but I get @threadID returned as NULL and consequently postDate also as NULL.

How do I get the variable @threadIDvar to be filled with the returned threadID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget the `:=` for [user variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) ,  @threadIDvar`:=`threads.id

Comment: Ah... That I forgot... Thank you :)